# Pgfplots: legend depth

Tags: pgfplots

Consider the MWE below. How can we adjust the size of the box around the legend such that it matches the contents?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=6cm]
    \addplot[domain=-2:2] {1};
    \addlegendentry{$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi_{2_2}}$};
    \addlegendentry{$f(x)=1$};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(5,0)}]
  \begin{axis}[width=6cm]
    \addplot[domain=-2:2] {1};
    \addlegendentry{$f(x)=1$};
  \end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see on the image below (left) the depth of the material is sort of ignored.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various approaches which work more or less well for different cases.

### 1) inner ysep

A simple solution could be set the inner y-separation `legend style={inner ysep=5pt}`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=6cm, legend style={inner ysep=5pt}]
    \addplot[domain=-2:2] {1};
    \addlegendentry{$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi_{2_2}}$};
    \addlegendentry{$f(x)=1$};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(5,0)}]
  \begin{axis}[width=6cm, legend style={inner ysep=5pt}]
    \addplot[domain=-2:2] {1};
    \addlegendentry{$f(x)=1$};
  \end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However you also increase the gap to the upper frame border:

[image]

### 2) text depth

```
legend style={nodes={text depth=1.5mm}}
```

Is a very elegant solution mentioned by @percusse in the comments. Some extra space is added below every item, also the last item, which maybe not desired in case the last item is no fraction.

### 3) row sep

If you have multiple legend entries (which you probably have, otherwise the legend is pointless) - and the last entry does not contain a fraction, then changing the `row sep` is the better option, as it doesn't adda gap neither on the top nor on bottom, just inbetween the items:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=6cm,legend style={row sep=5pt}]
    \addplot[domain=-2:2] {1};
    \addplot[domain=-2:2] {1};
    \addlegendentry{$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi_{2_2}}$};
    \addlegendentry{$f(x)=1$};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(5,0)}]
  \begin{axis}[width=6cm]
    \addplot[domain=-2:2] {1};
    \addlegendentry{$f(x)=1$};
  \end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### 4) parbox

Fiddling around with a `\parbox` could also be an option, case you just need a solution for a single particular item

```
\addlegendentry{\parbox[b][0.5cm][c]{2cm}{$f(x)=\frac{1\vphantom{2\pi^{2^2}}}{2\pi_{2_2}}$}};
```

### 5) semitransparent

Because of troubles like that I personally prefer something like:

```
\tikzset{semitransparent/.style = {draw=none, fill = white, fill opacity=0.8, text opacity = 1}}
```

and then

```
legend style={semitransparent}
```

over boxes.

Comment: That ought to work, too bad for the space above. I'll see what it looks like in my actual doc

Comment: Because of troubles like, I edited my answer for another idea, how I usually do it and more approaches to solve the original case.

Comment: Maybe `legend style={nodes={text depth=1.5mm}}` ?

Comment: @percusse seems to be a good option, too - but adds additional space to the bottom frame border in case the last entry has no fraction.

Comment: I think best option would be adding `\displaystyle` to the expression to render it a bit better. But didn't test it.

Comment: In this case I actually only have a single (constant) function.

Comment: I think I'll just use the solution  @percusse added. Looks fine

Comment: Do you mind showing percusses solution as well. Then I'll accept it. There will be enough solutions for someone else that comes by.

Comment: @daleif answer is completed.