# Ticklabels depths after rotation

Tags: pgfplots

I currently have an issue aligning ticklabels when using a comma as decimal separator. 
For `x ticklabels` the alignment works fine and no modification is required. However, for `y ticklabels`, I can't figure the right way to overcome the alignment problem. I tried `nodes={depth=somelength}` as in [Pgfplots: legend depth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400261/pgfplots-legend-depth) but it does not seem to work, seemingly due to the `rotate=90` option.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=7cm,
height=4cm,
/pgf/number format/use comma,
yticklabel style={nodes={text depth=100pt,anchor=north},rotate=90},
xticklabel style={nodes={text depth=100pt,anchor=north},rotate=0},
]
\addplot+[domain=0:1,samples=10] {x};
\addplot+[domain=0:1,samples=10] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Your syntax for y tick style is wrong ... for x ticks is default style OK.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=7cm,
height=4cm,
/pgf/number format/use comma,
yticklabel style={text depth=0.25ex,anchor=south,rotate=90},
]
\addplot+[domain=0:1,samples=10] {x};
\addplot+[domain=0:1,samples=10] {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: My bad, that was a far too easy one !