# Shrink to fit legend boxes - pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Occasionally we have legend entries which are of quite different sizes (lengths). This results in wasted real estate when legends are within the axis, and very large plots when they are outside the axis. If there are, for instance, roughly two lengths of legend entries (short and long) as shown below, it would be convenient to have a single legend box with customised dimensions.

My workaround for this has been to just create separate legend boxes:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[legend pos=south west, domain=0:100, no marks]
        \addplot+[orange] {0}; 
        \addlegendentry{long legend entry indeed}

        \addplot {-x + 1};  \label{a} 
        \addplot {-x + 4};  \label{b}
        \addplot {-x + 9};  \label{c}
        \addplot {-x + 1};  \label{d}

        % Desired look of legend box
        \draw (60,0) -- (80,0) -- (80, -20) -- (100,-20) -- (100, -30) -- (60, -30) -- (60, 0);
    \end{axis} % The following is quite tedious
    \begin{axis}[axis x line=none, axis y line=none, legend style={at={(axis cs:-5.63, -0.5)}, anchor=south west},]
        \addplot[opacity=0, forget plot] {0};
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=a}  \addlegendentry{$c_1$}
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=b}  \addlegendentry{$c_2$}
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=c}  \addlegendentry{$c_3$}
        \addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=d}  \addlegendentry{$c_4$}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that if a single legend box was used, it would cover up a substantial region of the plot. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400261/pgfplots-legend-depth?rq=1) post looks relevant, although `legend style` options such as `text depth` operate globally.

Comment: IIRC, the legend is formed using a tabular.  Alternatively, it is possible to construct a legent from scratch.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pgfplots does not seem to store the legend entries in nodes that we can easily access so the perhaps simplest option would be to use a path picture. Unfortunately, this means that we need to add two dimensions by hand.

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[legend pos=south west,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={fill=none,draw=none,
        path picture={\draw 
        ([xshift=\pgflinewidth/2,yshift=-\pgflinewidth/2]path picture bounding box.north west)
         -- ++ (3.5em,0cm) |-
        ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth/2,yshift=1.8em]path picture bounding box.south east) --
        ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth/2,yshift=\pgflinewidth/2]path picture bounding box.south east) 
        -| cycle;}
        },
         domain=0:100, no marks]

        \addplot {-x + 1};  
        \addlegendentry{$c_1$} 
        \addplot {-x + 4}; 
        \addlegendentry{$c_2$}
        \addplot {-x + 9}; 
        \addlegendentry{$c_3$}
        \addplot {-x + 1};  
        \addlegendentry{$c_4$}
        \addplot+[orange] {0}; 
        \addlegendentry{long legend entry indeed}

        % Desired look of legend box
        \draw (60,0) -- (80,0) -- (80, -20) -- (100,-20) -- (100, -30) -- (60, -30) -- (60, 0);
    \end{axis} % The following is quite tedious

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you remove all the `path picture` stuff and just keep `fill=none` you will get a legend without border, which my also do.

Comment: Where can I learn more about `path picture`? I couldn't find anything in my copy of the [documentation](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgfplots/).

Comment: @algae It is documented on p. 182 of the pgfmanual (!) v3.1.5, not the pgfplots manual.